# Linked StackExchange Accounts

Tags: support, reputation, stackexchange, linked-accounts, openid

I have an account on StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser all linked to the same OpenID. I originally did not think much of it until I noticed I started gaining reputation/badges individually on each site. Are you supposed to gain reputation per each site, or if the accounts are linked is it supposed to be summed across all of StackExchange? I can see all of my accounts in the 'Accounts' tab of my profile, so I am guessing they are linked together (but not merged? if that means anything).

Comment: You can look at your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/fec90be8-2dfb-4916-a8dc-db39990b5117?tab=accounts) to see everything at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are you supposed to gain reputation per each site

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

The only area I know of where your *aggregate* reputation has meaning is in Area51 when it comes time to commit to new proposals. The more rep you have across the entire StackExchange, the more weight your committment has to that proposal.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess for reputation earned per each site/community it makes sense. As it shows how much you have worked there specifically. It just seems weird that you have to consistently earn the same privileges at each site with a linked account.

Comment: @Nicholi, you get all the basic abilities for free (via account association bonus) once you reach 200 rep on one site.  To get the bonus just re-associate all your accounts after you have reached 200 on one site.  The more advanced abilities like question closing and moderating really do need a lot of commitment to a specific site.  For example I really would not be a good judge about what should or should not be considered a good question on english.stackexchange.

Comment: @Nicholi Believe me, I know. When I drop by Security.se where I'm pretty low rep, the user experience is markedly different than it is on SF where I'm a moderator. And I still can't vote-to-close on SU.